# Codeigniter view sub folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to load a view from a subfolder the path is like so (views/pages/users/myview.php). I would like to set a href link for this. I have tried to change routes and code logic but nothing has worked. I have tried to just load a view as well but that did not work, I think this might be due to my routes but I am not sure. users was just moved to users/ in the views folder to try and that did not link to the pages.

Routes.php

```
 $route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
 $route['students/(:any)'] = 'pages/view_student/$1'; // try
 $route['pages/users/(:any)'] = 'pages/view_user/$1'; // try
 $route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

header.php

```
<div id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>login">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>user_main">Users</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>student_main">Student</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

pages.php

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller{

public function view($page = 'home'){

    if(!file_exists(APPPATH. 'views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){

        show_404();

    } // end if

    $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

} // end function VIEW

// try
public function view_user($page = 'user_main'){

    if(!file_exists(APPPATH. 'views/users/'.$page.'.php')){

        show_404();

    } // end if

    $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('users/'.$page, $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

} // end function VIEW

// try
public function view_student($page = 'student_main'){

    if(!file_exists(APPPATH. 'views/pages/students/'.$page.'.php')){

        show_404();

    } // end if

    $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('pages/students/'.$page, $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

} // end function VIEW

}   // end class
```

********************* EDIT BELOW *********************

I have been able to get this kinda working but, it is ugly and not very dynamic. I feel like there has to be a better way to access the files in users that will allow the original setup of the view method

in the view function:

```
$data['title'] = ucfirst($page);
    $segment = $this->uri->uri_string();

    $this->load->view('templates/header');

    if($segment == 'student_main')
        $this->load->view('pages/students/'.$page, $data);
    elseif($segment == 'user_main')
        $this->load->view('pages/users/'.$page, $data);
    else
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);

    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

in header:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>user_main">Users</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>student_main">Student</a></li>
```

Comment: Narrow the problem, please. What route you are trying to access?

Comment: Iam trying to access the php files in a subfolder of a subfolder in views, lets just say, I want user_main.php in users that is in pages. I assume that I could make a link like so... <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>user_main">Users</a> ; but this breaks on the view method

Comment: How code is written for now to access _user_main.php_ you should go to *http://example.com/pages/users/user_main* because just that segment you are calling to invoke same name class. Try with this link.

Comment: the above link gave a 404 error, but I was able to get "/user_main" to work with the following but, it is not very dynamic and seems clunky:  $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);
  $segment = $this->uri->uri_string();

  $this->load->view('templates/header');
  
  if($segment == 'student_main')
   $this->load->view('pages/students/'.$page, $data);
  elseif($segment == 'user_main')
   $this->load->view('pages/users/'.$page, $data);
  else
   $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
   
  $this->load->view('templates/footer');

Comment: Please, copy that and put in (edited) question in `code tags`. It's unbearable to my eyes.

Comment: Your default controller should just be Pages. No need to add the method 'views'.